# Unstable relay when using single power source

Tags: power-supply, relay, esp8266

I am trying to control a 5V fan using an ESP01 and a relay module from LC Technology.

The setup works when I use 2 power sources but my setup requires a single power source which is unstable. The relay turns on but turns off after a couple of seconds.

Stable setup:

[image]

Unstable setup:

[image]

I do not know all the electronic terminology, which has made it very hard to search for a possible solution. I hope someone here can help with the missing pieces.

The USB PSU supplies 2.5 amperes, which should be more than sufficient.

Comment: Can you measure any voltage drop? How much current does the fan pull?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try re-wiring like this and adding a 1000 uF capacitor: -

[image]

If this doesn't work then maybe your USB supply is dropping too low when the fan is activated. This could easily cause the circuit to reset.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I will try to find a 1000 uF capacitor to test with.

Comment: That worked like a charm!

Comment: @MartinPrintzlau i understand adding the capacitor. But why did you rewire the ground line like that? Why do they have to be connected directly from supply ground individually?

Comment: @UjjwalSyal to avoid volt drops down the load wires affecting the voltage presented to the MCU.